# Perl Can't modify constant item in substitution

Tags: perl, pdf

I have Perl Script using to remove unnecessary tags that bloating xml pdf files i am creating

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;

use DirHandle;

my $sourcefile = shift;
my $outputfile = "new" . $sourcefile;

open SOURCEFILE, "$sourcefile" or die;
open OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile" or die;

$flag = 0;
foreach $line (<SOURCEFILE>) {
  if($line=~ /<\?templateDesigner StyleID aped2\?>\n/) {
    if($flag == 1) {
      line=~ s/[\t]*<\?templateDesigner StyleID aped2\?>\n//gi;
    }
    $flag=1;
  }
  elsif($line=~ /<\?templateDesigner StyleID aped3\?>\n/) {
    if($flag == 1) {
      $line=~ s/[\t]*<\?templateDesigner StyleID aped3\?>\n//gi;
    }
    $flag=1;
  }
  elsif($line=~ /<\?templateDesigner StyleID apcb1\?>\n/) {
    if($flag == 1) {
      $line=~ s/[\t]*<\?templateDesigner StyleID apcb1\?>\n//gi;
    }
    $flag=1;
  }
  else {
    $flag=0;
  }
  print OUTPUTFILE $line;
}

close SOURCEFILE;
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Result of me running this script is following error.

Can't modify constant item in substitution (s///) at d:\Temp\PDFPatch2.pl line 1
7, near "s/[\t]*<\?templateDesigner StyleID aped2\?>\n//gi;"
Execution of d:\Temp\PDFPatch2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Sorry do not know much about perl.

Comment: Don't turn off `strict`. Turn on `warnings`.  This would perhaps make it clear that you've typoed on line 17, and omitted `$` from in front of `$line`.

Comment: Turning off `strict` and `warnings` is like driving in the dark without a seat belt: It doesn't make it safer to drive, you just don't see the danger until you crash.

Comment: The error messages are *not the problem*. They are valuable signposts *to* the problem. Just switching them off and then asking for help is a little crazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't turn off `strict`. 
Turn on `warnings`.

This would perhaps make it clear that you've typoed on line 17, and omitted `$` from in front of `$line`.

Comment: I have added `$` in front of line and turned on strict and warnings.   Now i am getting following error message.  Really sorry but i am such a noobie when comes to perl. Global symbol "$flag" requires explicit package name at d:\Temp\PDFPatch2.pl line 14.

Comment: I have added `my` in front of `$flag` and `$line`.  This now declares a variable i can use.  Now just getting a message `Died at d:\Temp\PDFPatch2.pl line 12.`

Comment: `open OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile" or die;`. Change that to `die $!` and it will tell you why it couldn't open the file.

Comment: Ok i figured out last problem when using my script i should not specify full path of the file as will lead to invalid path because the word new will be added to the front.